# How can I record Minecraft with Roxio PC Game Capture?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, roxio-pc-game-capture

Just bought Roxio PC Game Capture to record Minecraft sessions.

I've set up as per instructions but no matter what I try it doesn't want to record Minecraft.  Has anyone used this software with Minecraft successfully? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Just a note on the possible source of the problem: Minecraft uses OpenGL as the graphics library instead of DirectX like many PC games.  It's possible that your software can only tap into DirectX buffers.

Comment: Saying something "doesn't want" to work is the worst way to describe a problem. In what exact manner does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't use Roxio Game Capture, but I do know that it is highly sensitive; my friend was having a few issues getting it to work too:

- Start up Minecraft, THEN start up Roxio Game Capture (order matters)
- Do NOT resize the game screen. Game Capture is especially sensitive

You should probably post more specific qualifiers with the problem though, for instance:

- Your computer specs
- The update version of Minecraft you are using (hopefully most recent)
- The version of Roxio Game Capture that you are using (again, hopefully most updated)
- Any and all mods of Minecraft you are running

Additional thought, unless you are bent on using Roxio Game Capture, check out Camtasia or Fraps, they are much more user friendly and versatile.

Comment: Or Bandicam if you like hard drive space. :)

Comment: Hard drive space = smard drive shace, amirite?

Comment: FRAPS may be friendly to use, but it's not exactly kind to your hard disk space...